# NoMethodError undefined method `encoding' for nil:NilClass CGI.escape

Tags: ruby-on-rails

came across this problem a little earlier today, anyone know what might be going on?  I'm a rookie with api's.  Tried Googling but not much luck so far..

Error:

```
NoMethodError in ArtistsController#index
undefined method `encoding' for nil:NilClass
```

the problem line is:

```
response = HTTParty.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=#{CGI.escape params[:query]}&type=artist")
```

which makes me think it might be an issue with CGI.escape.

If I enter the following url with a query already at the end everything works fine:
`http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=Caribou&commit=Search`

However, if enter the following url without a query I get the error mentioned above:
`http://localhost:3000/search`

Guess that explains the nil part, but I don't no how to get past this..

Think that's all the info I need to give for this issue but let me know if more is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If `params[:query]` isn't defined, then `CGI.escape` is receiving a nil argument.

Make sure `params[:query]` is defined if you're referencing it, and/or don't call `CGI.escape` when searching by type only, and not keyword. (Assuming that's possible--that's what the empty search above seems to imply.)

Comment: How do I define params[:query] so that it will dynamically equal what a user actually inputs for a search query?  First time doing this.